# Keep printing direction before the returns - Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I use python to code on VScode. Every time I executed it, a long string of direction comes out before the returns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). It runs your code with clear output. To install it press `⌘+P` in VS Code and paste

```
ext install formulahendry.code-runner
```

You can run your code with triangle in right upper corner or from context menu.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I tried code runner, it does not work. Is it because my setting? can I alter my setting to remove that?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? To uninstall it go to `View` -> `Extensions`, find Code Runner, click a gear near it and select `Uninstall`.

Comment: Code runner does not work. I did what you recommend by installing code runner and run the code. The direction just don't go away, so I reckon it is my setting.